# Append/Create CSV file

Tags: batch-file

I have pipe-delimiters text file with header and has multiple columns, first column indicates csv file name, I want to append the data to csv file from column 2 onwards, if csv file does not exist create new with headers.

```
 col1|col2|col3|col4|col5
 toll1|12042014|xxxx|xxxx|xxxxx
 toll2|13042014|xxxx|xxxx|xxxxx

 csv file [toll1.csv]
 col2|col3|col4|col5
 12042014|xxxx|xxxx|xxxxx

 csv file [toll2.csv]
 col2|col3|col4|col5
 13042014|xxxx|xxxx|xxxxx
```

Comment: Start with `For /F "tokens=1-5 delims=^|" %G in (tolls.csv) do @echo %G %H %I %J %K` from command line (to run in a '.bat' batch you should double all % sign: use %%G etc.). Then you could alter the result changing `tokens=1-5` to `tokens=1*` etc. Note escaped pipe in `delims=^|`. Feel free to update your question with actual achievements and ask more in case you crane at something. [Learn more ...](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set headerRow=
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=^|" %%a in (tolls.csv) do (
    if not defined headerRow (
        set headerRow=%%b
    ) else (
        if not exist "%%a.csv" echo !headerRow!>>"%%a.csv"
        echo %%b>>"%%a.csv"
    )
)
endlocal
```